# find minimum value by grouping the timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, jdbc, group-by

How to find the minimum value from the following set or records in sql

```
Date                       Values
-------------------------  ------
 2013-07-20 18:05:38.599   257
 2013-07-20 18:06:39.264   118
 2013-07-20 18:07:39.51    142
 2013-07-20 18:08:39.67    138
 2013-07-20 18:09:40.279   123
 2013-07-20 18:10:40.697   115
 2013-07-20 18:11:41.158   124
 2013-07-20 18:12:41.327   128
 2013-07-20 18:13:41.797   533
 2013-07-20 18:14:42.345   129
 2013-07-20 18:15:42.694   124
 2013-07-20 18:16:43.222   114
 2013-07-20 18:17:43.715   119
 2013-07-20 18:18:44.162   126
```

I need to find the minimum value for every 3 min of the timestamp. Can anyone please suggest a query to work this??

Comment: Provide some examples of what you have already tried please.

Comment: `select * from table 
where (date,values) IN (select date,min(value) from table group by date);` But I know this query doesnt solve the problem. I am jus a beginner in sql. The groupby should include the addition of 3 min. But  I m confused how to implement it. Sorry.

Comment: What does "every three minutes" mean to you? Is the first three-minute bucket the half-open interval from [18:05:00 -- 18:08:00), or is it from [18:05:38 -- 18:08:38), or seomething else?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': First three minute bucket is something like this [18:05:38 -- 18:08:38]

Answer (score 0):

Always specify your dbms, and provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question.

```
create table test (
  date timestamp,
  value integer
);
insert into test values
('2013-07-20 18:05:38.599',   257),
('2013-07-20 18:06:39.264',   118),
('2013-07-20 18:07:39.51',    142),
('2013-07-20 18:08:39.67',    138),
('2013-07-20 18:09:40.279',   123),
('2013-07-20 18:10:40.697',   115),
('2013-07-20 18:11:41.158',   124),
('2013-07-20 18:12:41.327',   128),
('2013-07-20 18:13:41.797',   533),
('2013-07-20 18:14:42.345',   129),
('2013-07-20 18:15:42.694',   124),
('2013-07-20 18:16:43.222',   114),
('2013-07-20 18:17:43.715',   119),
('2013-07-20 18:18:44.162',   126);
```

Use your platform's date/time functions to generate a virtual table of "buckets", each one containing an interval of three minutes. *Exactly* how you do this varies among SQL platforms, because date/time functions vary a lot among SQL platforms. I'm using PostgreSQL, so I'm going to use its generate_series() function in a common table expression.

```
with buckets as (
  select n as start_time, n + interval '3' minute as end_time
  from generate_series(timestamp '2013-07-20 18:05:38.599', 
                       timestamp '2013-07-20 18:18:44.162', 
                       '3 minutes') n
)
select min(test.value), start_time, end_time
from test
inner join buckets on test.date >= start_time and test.date < end_time
group by start_time, end_time
order by start_time;

118  2013-07-20 18:05:38.599  2013-07-20 18:08:38.599
115  2013-07-20 18:08:38.599  2013-07-20 18:11:38.599
124  2013-07-20 18:11:38.599  2013-07-20 18:14:38.599
114  2013-07-20 18:14:38.599  2013-07-20 18:17:38.599
119  2013-07-20 18:17:38.599  2013-07-20 18:20:38.599
```